# Supervisor HTTP Server Port Issue

Tags: supervisord

I have supervisor setup to manage a few processes. It works perfectly fine when I boot my server, however when I stop it and try to start it again it fails and give's me this error msg:

```
 * Starting Supervisor daemon manager...
Error: Another program is already listening on a port that one of our HTTP servers is configured to use.  Shut this program down first before starting supervisord.
For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
   ...fail!
```

I'm running nginx on port 80 and 4 web servers on ports 8000, 8001, 8002, 8003

Does anyone have any idea of what is going on?

When I reboot everything works fine.

Answer (score 93):

Just ran into this as well.  I fixed it by doing either of these:

```
sudo unlink /tmp/supervisor.sock

sudo unlink /var/run/supervisor.sock
```

This `.sock` file is defined in `/etc/supervisord.conf [unix_http_server]` file config value (default is `/tmp/supervisor.sock` or `/var/run/supervisor.sock`).

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: @sdolan Wow it helped me! I removed /var/run/supervisor.sock and got rid of error on Debian Stable

Comment: run a find / -name supervisor.sock before you run unlink - on debian systems it sits in /var/run/, but your unlink solution worked for me

Comment: Why doesn't supervisor terminate with an error code to allow scripts to unlink automatically and retry?

Comment: Be careful here. After unlinking, run "ps -ef | grep supervisord" and you'll see that the old process is still running. You may want to "kill <process_id>" as well. EDIT: This was my case while using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: After the unlink command I am trying to restart supervisor but now the .sock is missed. ```unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock no such file```. So what else do I need to do.

Answer (score 9):

I'd use lsof to find out what process is listening on those ports.

`lsof -i tcp | grep LISTEN`

Once you've worked out what process it is, that's half the battle.

Answer (score 1):

This would generally not be the case with you but I was hitting this error when I was mistakingly using `supervisord` instead of `supervisorctl`.